# ASP.net core namespaces out of sync

Tags: c#, namespaces, asp.net-core-mvc

I decided to change the name of a folder within "Models->ABC->A" to "Models->ABC->B" Manually.
the problem is, now in the view imports i'm getting old suggestions A but not B. i don't understand where the A is coming from? i cleaned the solution, rebuilt the solution. checked in directory but A doesn't exists there still it shows A in suggestion. it seems when i build the project Visual Studio (2019 Community) is using the same old data and namespaces are out of sync. any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `namespace` given in the `Class` is having the old `namespace` that is Models->ABC->A. Change it to Models->ABC->B.